# Basis of intersection of two subspaces of different dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have :

Basis of subspace $A$ :$\Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 0\\1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 0\\0 \end{pmatrix}  \Bigg\}$

Basis of subspace $B$: $\Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} -7 \\ 1 \\ 1\\0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -7 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ -1\\1 \end{pmatrix}   , \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\\-2 \end{pmatrix}  \Bigg\}$

How do I find a basis for the intersection $A \cap B$?

I have seen similar questions on this site, but the two bases had the same number of vectors so the procedure was easy.

Comment: If these are really bases, what do you know about $\dim A$ and $\dim B$ and where do these subspaces live?

Comment: Does basis of A consist of 3 vectors and that of B of 4 vectors?

Comment: @TedShifrin My thinking is that $A \subset B$ because the vectors in the basis of $B$ are linearly independent so they are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: $\Bbb R^4$, you mean. And, it might help if you put in all the commas in your lists of vectors. I think you might be confusing people. :) But, yes, you're right.

Comment: @fornit So you see it : $B$ is just $\mathbb R^4$(since it's a basis of a four dimensional subspace that consists of for elements), therefore all you need to see is that $A \cap B = A$, and the answer follows.

Comment: @fornit If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\dim B = 4\implies A \cap B=A\cap \mathbb{R}=A$$